# Fitting table with 2 tabularx environment (Beamer)

Tags: tables, beamer, tabularx

I am trying to make a big table fit into a beamer slide. My table has 2 panels which are 2 `tabularx` environments. My attempt involves one `\resizebox` for each `tabularx` environment (see code below).

If I put the 2 `tabularx` in the same `\resizebox`, then I get an error because I'm using `\\ [0.3cm]` to have some space between the 2 panels.  I'm wondering whether there exists a better solution than this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..{-1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of my slide}
\begin{table}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{d}}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCC$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCCCCCCCCC$}
 \\
 \midrule

 \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: AAA}} \\
 \midrule
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
  \end{tabular}

 \vfill


 \begin{tabular}{c*{7}{d}}

 \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: BBB}} \\
 \midrule
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
  \midrule
  \end{tabular}

  \end{table}
  \end{frame}



 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: `\\[0.3cm] % space between panels` is wrong. use `\bigskip` or `\vspace{.3cm}` or whatever

Comment: `\resizebox{8cm}{!} {
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}` you are making tabularx force the table width to be `\textwidth` then scaling it (and two word spaces) to 8cm? Why not set the table to the desired size without scaling?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're going to resize the entire content, you could also wrap all the frame content in a `{ \tiny \begin{table}[htb] ... \end{table} }` group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to avoid scaling tables, and avoid using `tabularx` for numeric data (`tabularx` adjusts column widths by changing the target width for *line breaking* but you don't normally want line breaking within cells for this kind of table)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of my slide}
\begin{table}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{d}}
\midrule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC1$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC2$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC3$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC4$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC5$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC6$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC7$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CC8$}
\\
\midrule

\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: AAA}} \\
\midrule
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
      & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
      & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
      & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
 \end{tabular}


\vfill


\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{d}}
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: BBB}} \\
\midrule
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
       & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
       & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
       & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
 \midrule
 \end{tabular}


 \end{table}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David, thanks a lot for your precious help. May I ask one last thing? I notice that I have columns titles slightly longer than 2 characters, the column titles are not aligned. Suppose I have:  $CCCC1$ & $CCC2$ & $CCC3$ & $CCC4$ & $CCC5$ & $CCC6$ & $CCCCC7$ & $CCCC8$   \\

Comment: @user3618451 answer updated to use `c` formatting rather than `d` for the header row.

Comment: David, thanks again for your answer. I have updated the initial code. I still have troubles when the column titles are really long. The 2nd panel has a smaller width than the first one. I'm also attaching an image this time.